# How to insert a column every n columns of a matrix without using apply or looping

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have a matrix

```
M = diag(6)
```

and I want to insert

```
d = rep(5,6)
```

every 3rd column so the output is

```
M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
> d
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]   [,6]  [,7]   [,8]
[1,]    1    0    0    5    0       0    0      5
[2,]    0    1    0    5    0       0    0      5
[3,]    0    0    1    5    0       0    0      5
[4,]    0    0    0    5    1       0    0      5
[5,]    0    0    0    5    0       1    0      5
[6,]    0    0    0    5    0       0    1      5
```

Comment: How big is your matrix?

Comment: Very big, millions of columns across and this calculation must be performed many many times as part of a fixed point algorithm, so it needs to be fast

Comment: If this related to your other question, might it be a possibility to add the newdata during the splitting/stacking process? Means you'll have to traverse the matrix only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create another `matrix` of 5 ('m1') by more number of columns, create column index (using `setdiff` and `seq`) to replace the values in 'm1' by 'M'

```
n <- 3
m1 <- matrix(5, ncol=ncol(M)+ncol(M)/n, nrow=nrow(M))
m1[,setdiff(1:ncol(m1),seq(4, ncol(m1), by=4))] <- M
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    0    0    5    0    0    0    5
#[2,]    0    1    0    5    0    0    0    5
#[3,]    0    0    1    5    0    0    0    5
#[4,]    0    0    0    5    1    0    0    5
#[5,]    0    0    0    5    0    1    0    5
#[6,]    0    0    0    5    0    0    1    5
```

EDIT:

I guess instead of creating another huge `matrix`, it might be memory efficient to `cbind` additional columns and then `order` the columns

```
n1 <- ncol(M)/n
M1 <- matrix(5, nrow=nrow(M), ncol=n1)
M2 <- cbind(M, M1) 
n2 <- seq(4, ncol(M2), by=4)
M3 <- M2[,order(c(setdiff(seq_len(ncol(M2)), n2), n2))]
M3
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    0    0    5    0    0    0    5
#[2,]    0    1    0    5    0    0    0    5
#[3,]    0    0    1    5    0    0    0    5
#[4,]    0    0    0    5    1    0    0    5
#[5,]    0    0    0    5    0    1    0    5
#[6,]    0    0    0    5    0    0    1    5
```

#### Benchmarks

```
M <- diag(5000)
n <- 3
system.time({
n1 <- ncol(M)/n
M1 <- matrix(5, nrow=nrow(M), ncol=n1)
M2 <- cbind(M, M1) 
n2 <- seq(n+1, ncol(M2), by=n+1)
M3 <- M2[,order(c(setdiff(seq_len(ncol(M2)), n2), n2))]
})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.699   0.068   0.769 

n <- 3
system.time({
m1 <- matrix(5, ncol=ncol(M)+ncol(M)/n, nrow=nrow(M))
m1[,setdiff(1:ncol(m1),seq(n+1, ncol(m1), by=n+1))] <- M
})
#user  system elapsed 
#  0.722   0.061   0.785 

identical(m1, M3)
#[1] TRUE
```